# Using github and MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, git, mamp, gitignore

I have MAMP setup on my mac, and I have a web app installed in the htdocs folder that use my mysql databases. So far everything is working great. The problem is the project is using git, so I installed the github mac app. Theres a .gitignore file that includes a bunch of files, but I'll just list one to explain my problem. This file is in in .gitignore:

```
/application/config/development/database.php
```

But, when I make changes to it, it displays in my change list. Using the github mac app, I right click and choose ignore, and it inserts this path into my .gitignore file:

```
application/config/development/database.php
```

Notice the missing '/'. But then, .gitignore shows up in my uncommitted files, and the database.php file is not ignored! Also, `.gitgnore` is in the .gitignore file as well. Is this a relative path problem? A git installation problem? Halp!

Comment: You can always open the `.gitignore` file and edit it manually, it's just a text file, and I don't think ignoring the `gitignore` works, at least never did with me, and I didn't really try to search if it can be done or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `.gitignore` is commited (and pushed) like any other project relevant file. When it shows up under changed (but not staged) files, it is ok. You should commit and push it.

The fact that`.gitignore` contains itself makes absolutely not sense, I would recommend to remove this line.

The paths in `.gitignore` are relative to its location. When `.gitignore` is in `/home/foo/bar` then `/herp/derp.php` in `.gitignore` means

```
/home/foo/bar/herp/derp.php
```

whereas `herp/derp.php` in `.gitignore` will match

```
/home/foo/bar/herp/derp.php
```

as well as

```
/home/foo/bar/baz/herp/derp.php
```

The fact that the `database.php` shows up under changed/uncommited files means quite sure, that this file previously has been commited. You will havt to remove it from the working tree:

```
$ git rm /application/config/development/database.php
```

and commit the changes along with the changes in `.gitignore`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! My remaining question then is...why would the github Mac App add `application/config/development/database.php` when I choose 'Ignore' via the UI? .gitignore is in the same directory as the  application folder.

Comment: You have to ask the github app :) It should usually be no problem. I guess the app does this by default. But as I said, no problem. I'd appreciate you to accept and upvote my answer. Thanks alot!